# How do I organise multiple src directories in the same Java Project in eclipse as seperate namespaces?

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans, namespaces

Namespace conventions and src code organization in eclipse:
Here's my problem:- 
I am working on an Oracle certification lab built for netbeans but from within eclipse. In eclipse, I would like to:

- work from multiple src directories in the same Java Project
- define a namespace scope for each of the chapters in the course material
- avoid duplicate class names whilst in separate source directories,they share the same package structure.

This will enable me to work on multiple classes with the same name but avoid type errors due to the namespace seeing all other classes in the structure.

. In netbeans I can load up seperate projects and scope the namespace per directory tree top level folder to avoid clashes. How do I do this in eclipse..
[screenshot showing the problem (notice the errors highlighted, package structure and class names)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TtLs0.jpg)

Comment: You can't do this, use multiple projects.

Comment: Thank you I figured it out thanks to your comment!! Is it best practice to use a different workspace to switch between different code bases. I guess it's not possible to have nested projects ... ?

Comment: It is up to you how many workspaces you use. I have a separate workspace for each application.